# How to distinguish the events from azure eventhub for many roles?

Tags: azure, servicebus

We have 2 workroles to consume data from an EventHub,  all the roles will get same data?  do we have a way to distinguish the data for the roles: like if the data was readed by role1, the role2 can not read the data?

Comment: Are EventHubs the right choice for your app?  If you have specific conditions surrounding data received by different roles, maybe Topic Queues with appropriate subscriptions is what you really want?

Comment: Yes consider using topics, you can apply subscription filter at different worker-roles

Comment: Event Hub are more suited for publishing same notification to multiple devices etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, typically, if 2 roles are consuming data from EventHub (assuming that you are using [EventProcessorHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost%28v=azure.95%29.aspx) to Consume events) - they are guarenteed to read from different partitions. For ex: if your EventHub has 16 partitions, EventProcessorHost will make sure to load balance 2 roles to read from 8 partitions each.